# Help removing handles from my faucet

Tags: faucet

There is no screw (or covered screw) to remove the handles from this sink. I do not know the brand name.

[image]

[image]

**Update: I figure it out how to unscrew it.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like there is to me. On the right handle pictured, is that a hole? approx 1/16" wide? look inside, it probably needs an allen key wrench.

Comment: Thank you.  I have figure it out how to unscrew it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Since you figured it out, would you post your solution as an answer, so others can benefit from your knowledge? Thanks.

Comment: remove the cap.  And then unscrew it.